# Add Objects to NSArray as NSNumber numberWithBool:NO - ObjC to Xamarin

Tags: c#, ios, objective-c, xamarin, xamarin.ios

I'm trying to add objects to the array as NSNumber numberWithBool: NO in Xamarin.iOS, but somehow I couldn't convert it xamarin.iOS.

I would like to know the Xamarin.iOS equivalent to the below ObjC code

```
[boolArray addObject:[NSNumber numberWithBool:NO]];
if ([[boolArray objectAtIndex:section] boolValue])
BOOL dataCell  = [[boolArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.section] boolValue];
```

Thanks

-----Edited-----

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Assuming boolArray is an `NSMutableArray`:

```
boolArray.Add(NSNumber.FromBoolean(false));
```

NSArray's selector `objectAtIndex:` maps to `ValueAt`

```
if (boolArray.ValueAt(section) == boolValue)
```

But you give no context of what `boolValue` is defined as, but assuming you need to get an `NSObject` from an `IntPtr`, you can use the `ObjCRuntime.Runtime`:

```
ObjCRuntime.Runtime.GetNSObject(someIntPtr)
```

Comment: Thanks, SushilHangover. yes, boolArray is NSMutableArray. If I use ValueAt, I'm getting "cannot convert from System.nint to System.nuint". Even I'm not sure what the boolValue is. I referred this site - http://www.iostute.com/2015/04/expandable-and-collapsable-tableview.html and trying to convert this to xamarin.iOS. I have added the error screenshot.

Comment: @user3310076 boolValue is defined in ObjC as `BOOL` type, they are just converting the returned object to a bool, you can just use a `List<bool>` to store your bool array, there is no need for a one 2 one literal translation as you are not passing that array to some Framework or 3rd-party ObjC API.